Robotics PD controller
I'd like to share my code. I'm having trouble understanding why my robot doesn't reach the desired positions when I increase the value of Kp. The robot has six degrees of freedom, and I'm using a PD control law to manipulate it.
https://github.com/tommasoandina1/Doosan_h2515/blob/main/esempio2.py
I want the actual joint positions of the robot to converge to the desired position
"In my robot's dynamics, the joint acceleration (ddq) is computed as follows: ddq = M^-1 * (tau - h), where M is the mass matrix, h is the bias force, and tau is the control law. The control law (tau) is defined as kp * (q_des - q) - kd * dq, where q is the joint position, dq is the joint velocity, and kp and kd are the proportional and derivative gains, respectively
and q = dt * dq
dq = dt * ddq

I tried to increase the kp and kd but it doesn't change

here there is the plot:
https://github.com/tommasoandina1/Doosan_h2515/blob/main/Figure_1.png

DO NOT post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers.
